# Vagrant OS X CentOS 7 - Shared folder owned by user 501, group games shared when using nfs

Tags: macos, centos, vagrant, centos7

I have a CentOS 7 vagrant. When I try to use nfs for sharing a folder the folder gets owned by the user 501 of the "games" group:

```
[vagrant@site-dev ~]$ ls -la
total 28
drwx-----x.  6 vagrant vagrant  180 feb 27 21:18 .
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root    root      21 dic 15 11:14 ..
drwxrwxr-x.  3 vagrant vagrant   17 feb 24 17:46 .ansible
-rw-rw-r--.  1 vagrant vagrant   17 feb 27 20:46 app.php
-rw-------.  1 vagrant vagrant 4811 feb 27 21:47 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--.  1 vagrant vagrant   18 dic  6 23:19 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--.  1 vagrant vagrant  193 dic  6 23:19 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--.  1 vagrant vagrant  231 dic  6 23:19 .bashrc
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 vagrant vagrant    0 feb 27 20:49 index.html
drwxrwxr-x.  2 vagrant vagrant   78 feb 24 18:17 .phpstorm_helpers
drwx------.  2 vagrant vagrant   29 feb 24 17:45 .ssh
drwxrwxrwx. 22     501 games    748 feb 27 21:47 www
```

The strange thing is that if I remove the nfs option from the Vagrantfile then I don't have that problem (but performance drops)

Here's my Vagrantfile config without the nfs option

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8088
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.150"

  config.vm.hostname = "site-dev"

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/vagrant/www"

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
  end

  config.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "ansible/playbook.yml"
    ansible.verbose = 'vvv'
    ansible.inventory_path = "ansible/hosts"
    ansible.limit = 'development'
  end
end
```

Any idea why this is happening and how I can use nfs for the shared folder?

Answer (score 0):

It should not be much of an issue - Mitchell explains [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/vagrant-up/-J3UEqYXveA)

> NFS works by simply shuttling files and metadata over from server to
>   client, which means permissions can't be changed mid-way. I've
>   configured NFS by default to the common-case, which is that even
>   though the uid/gid is 501/20, every user on the VM should be able to
>   write to it (go ahead, try it!).
>
> In practice, this has never been a problem for serving any web
>   applications.

If you really want to have correct username shows in `ls` command you can look at the [vagrant bindfs plugin](https://github.com/gael-ian/vagrant-bindfs)

Comment: actually it is an issue... using nginx and php-fpm I'm getting 403 errors because the nginx user can not access the document root files

Comment: @petekaner I'm experiencing the same issue with PHP7, Centos7 and Apache. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: yes, what i did was "setenforce Permissive" and also be sure your php file have exec permissions